# Merge data from two arrays or something else

Tags: c#

How to combine `Id` from the list I get from file `/test.json` and `id` from list `ourOrders[i].id`?
Or if there is another way?

```
private RegionModel FilterByOurOrders(RegionModel region, List<OurOrderModel> ourOrders, MarketSettings market, bool byOurOrders)
{
    var result = new RegionModel
    {
        updatedTs = region.updatedTs,
        orders = new List<OrderModel>(region.orders.Count)
    };

    var json = File.ReadAllText("/test.json");
    var otherBotOrders = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<OrdersTimesModel>(json);
    OtherBotOrders = new Dictionary<string, OrderTimesInfoModel>();

    foreach (var otherBotOrder in otherBotOrders.OrdersTimesInfo)
    {
        //OtherBotOrders.Add(otherBotOrder.Id, otherBotOrder);
        BotController.WriteLine($"{otherBotOrder.Id}"); //Output ID orders to the console works
    }

    foreach (var order in region.orders)
    {
        if (ConvertToDecimal(order.price) < 1 || !byOurOrders)
        {
            int i = 0;
            var isOurOrder = false;
            while (i < ourOrders.Count && !isOurOrder)
            {
                if (ourOrders[i].id.Equals(order.id, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    isOurOrder = true;
                }
                ++i;
            }
            if (!isOurOrder)
            {
                result.orders.Add(order);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

OrdersTimesModel Looks like that:

```
public class OrdersTimesModel
{
    public List<OrderTimesInfoModel> OrdersTimesInfo { get; set; }
}
```

test.json:

```
{"OrdersTimesInfo":[{"Id":"1"},{"Id":"2"}]}
```

**Added:**
I'll try to clarify the question:
There are three lists with ID:
`First (all orders)`: `region.orders`, as `order.id`
`Second (our orders)`: `ourOrders`, as `ourOrders[i].id` in a while loop
`Third (our orders 2)`: from the `/test.json` file, as an array `{"Orders":[{"Id":"12345..."...},{"Id":"12345..." ...}...]}`

There is a `foreach` in which there is a `while`, where the `First (all orders)` list and the `Second (our orders)` list are compared. If the `id`'s match, then these are our orders: `isOurOrder = true`;
Accordingly, those orders that `isOurOrder = false`; will be added to the `result`: `result.orders.Add(order)`

I need:
So that `if (ourOrders[i].id.Equals(order.id, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))` would include more `Id`'s from the `Third (our orders 2)` list.
Or any other way to do it?

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample scenario? Sample inputs and what output you wish to get

Comment: Hi there! Let me get this straight, you have an "allOrders" array, and a "ourOrders" array, and you want to compare those two and add to the result only the values in "allOrders" that are not in "ourOrders" right?

My doubt is, what is that /test.json file doing there? what's the goal of it?

Comment: There are two versions of the program and I need the file with orders from another program to be also taken into account as `ourOrders`. But in this file there is only a list of `Id`: `{"Orders":[{"Id":"12345..."...},{"Id":"12345..." ...}...]}`

Comment: What does OurOrderModel look like?  It looks like you only need Ids.  So var newList = otherBotOrders.OrdersTimesInfo.Select (o => o.Id).ToList(); then newList.AddRange(ourOrders.Select(o => o.id));  That would give you a list of the ids of both lists and then use newList inside the loop where you do the comparision.

Comment: @ScottMildenberger You wrote everything correctly, only id's. But how and where to use newList ? Where to paste. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I did. Your way works too. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to completely avoid writing loops if you use LINQ (there will be loops running in the background, but it's way easier to read)

You can access some documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries

and you have some pretty cool extension methods for arrays: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=net-6.0 (these are great to get your code easy to read)

### Solution

```
unsing System.Linq;

private RegionModel FilterByOurOrders(RegionModel region, List<OurOrderModel> ourOrders, MarketSettings market, bool byOurOrders)
{
    var result = new RegionModel
    {
        updatedTs = region.updatedTs,
        orders = new List<OrderModel>(region.orders.Count)
    };

    var json = File.ReadAllText("/test.json");
    var otherBotOrders = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<OrdersTimesModel>(json);

    // This line should get you an array containing 
    // JUST the ids in the JSON file
    var idsFromJsonFile = otherBotOrders.Select(x => x.Id);

    // Here you'll get an array with the ids for your orders
    var idsFromOurOrders = ourOrders.Select(x => x.id);

    // Union will only take unique values,
    // so you avoid repetition.
    var mergedArrays = idsFromJsonFile.Union(idsFromOurOrders);

    // Now we just need to query the region orders
    // We'll get every element that has an id contained in the arrays we created earlier
    var filteredRegionOrders = region.orders.Where(x => !mergedArrays.Contains(x.id));

    result.orders.AddRange(filteredRegionOrders );

    return result;
}
```

You can add conditions to any of those actions (like checking for order price or the boolean flag you get as a parameter), and of course you can do it without assigning so many variables, I did it that way just to make it easier to explain.

Comment: It is very good! Works. Can an example with `if (ConvertToDecimal(order.price) < 1)` in `region.orders`?